# Handling network timeouts in Java

Tags: java, timeout

i have a java program connect to server through xot protocol.

My lib i use can handle connect timeout, but there is no method like setSoTimeout() to handle timeout when send & recv data.

so, anyone could suggest me some solution for this problem.

thanks

Quan

Answer (score 0):

One option is to spawn a thread to do the writing and [`join(timeout)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) it.  Likewise with reading from the connection.  Obviously kill the thread (and treat the connection as in an indeterminate state) when the timeout expires (as opposed to the thread dieing).

Comment: maybe i create a new question :D

Answer (score 0):

'Socket.setSoTimeout()' should apply to recv as well. See its [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29).

> public void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException
>
> ```
> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
> ```
>
> With this option set to a non-zero
>   timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with this
>   Socket will block for only this amount
>   of time. If the timeout expires, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is
>   raised, though the Socket is still
>   valid. The option must be enabled
>   prior to entering the blocking
>   operation to have effect. The timeout
>   must be > 0. A timeout of zero is
>   interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Comment: my protocol is xot (x25 over tcp/ip) & i use other lib for this protocol, no use java socket (but similar :D )